# Capitalize first letter of every other array element

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, algorithm, methods

I have an array of elements, `["apple", "cherry", "raspberry", "banana", "pomegranate"]`, and I want it so that every odd element is capitalized: `["Apple", "cherry", "Raspberry", "banana", "Pomegranate"]`.

I can capitalize every element in the array, and I can filter out every odd element, but not at the same time (i.e. filtering only shows the odd elements).

Does anyone have any approaches and/or recommendations for this? I've seen questions about capitalizing every other letter, retrieving every other array element, etc., but nothing like what I've asked (yet, I'm still looking).

```js
function alts(arr) {
    const newArr = arr.filter((el, idx) => {
        if (idx % 2 === 0) {
            return arr.map(a => a.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + a.substr(1));
        }
    })
    return newArr;
}

console.log(alts(["apple", "cherry", "raspberry", "banana", "pomegranate"]));
// Just returns [ 'apple', 'raspberry', 'pomegranate' ]
```

Comment: Do you know if there will no empty strings at the even indexes of the input `arr`?

If you do not you might want to add a check for that or preprocess it beforehand because I think your existing answer and all the answers will throw an error otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
function alts(arr) {
    return arr.map((el, idx) => {
        return idx % 2 == 0 ? el.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + el.substr(1) : el;
    })
}

console.log(alts(["apple", "cherry", "raspberry", "banana", "pomegranate"]));
```

I map through the array and if the element's index is even (that's because index starts from 0, so it's flipped for us as we start counting from 1) then return the element with first letter capitalized, if it's an odd index, then just return the element itself.

Answer (score 2):

Map instead of filtering - inside the callback, if even, return the capitalized portion, else return the original string:

```js
function alts(arr) {
  return arr.map((str, i) => i % 2 === 1 ? str : str[0].toUpperCase() + str.slice(1));
}

console.log(alts(["apple", "cherry", "raspberry", "banana", "pomegranate"]));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple `for-loop` as follows:

```js
function alts(arr=[]) {
  const newArr = [...arr];
  for(let i = 0; i < newArr.length; i+=2) {
    const current = newArr[i];
    if(current)
      newArr[i] = current.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + current.substr(1);
  }
  return newArr;
}

console.log(alts(["apple", "cherry", "raspberry", "banana", "pomegranate"]));
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function alts(arr) {
  return arr.map((item, index) => {
    if (index % 2 === 0) {
      return item.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + item.substr(1);
    } else {
      return item
    }
  });
}

console.log(alts(["apple", "cherry", "raspberry", "banana", "pomegranate"]));
// Just returns [ 'apple', 'raspberry', 'pomegranate' ]
```